# Disable Scrolling Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a light box on my page. I would like to disable the following function when the light box is opened and enable it again when the light box is closed.

Here is the code for the function:

```
$.fn.fullpage.setMouseWheelScrolling = function (value){
        if(value){
            addMouseWheelHandler();
        }else{
            removeMouseWheelHandler();
        }
};
```

HTML for the light box:

```
<div>
    <a class="example_open" href="#example">View Popup</a>
</div> 
<div id="example" class="popup"> 
    <div class="content">abc</div> 
    <button class="example_close"></button> 
</div>
```

I'm using [this plugin for the light box](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Accessible-jQuery-Modal-Plugin-Popup-Overlay/)

How can I disable / enable the function based on the light box being visible?

Comment: Include the html for your lightbox and which lightbox plugin you are using

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable scrolling temporarily?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)

Comment: Here is the code:

<div><a class="example_open" href="#example">View Popup</a></div>

<div id="example" class="popup">
<div class="content">abc</div>
<button class="example_close"></button>
</div>

And the following plugin:
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Accessible-jQuery-Modal-Plugin-Popup-Overlay/

Comment: For next time, include that code and the plugin in the question itself. You can edit your question after you have posted it

Comment: @dehrg Acknowledged. Thanks for the guideline brother.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean disabling scrolling for whole page so try this:

```
$('html, body').css({
    'overflow': 'hidden',
    'height': '100%'
})
```

And in order to restore to default state:

```
$('html, body').css({
    'overflow': 'auto',
    'height': 'auto'
})
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0apy48qg/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you are using has javascript events which you can tap into. You can use them to set a variable, and then check for that variable in your scrolling function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var isOpen;

    $('#my_popup').popup({
       onopen: function() {
           isOpen = true;
       },
       onclose: function() {
           isOpen = false;
       }
    });

    $.fn.fullpage.setMouseWheelScrolling = function (value){
       if ( ! isOpen ) {
           if(value){
               addMouseWheelHandler();
           }else{
               removeMouseWheelHandler();
           }
       }
    };
});
```

Comment: There is some syntax error in line no 7 onclose: function()

Comment: Missed a comma, revised my answer

Comment: It's not working. Let me give you the project link. Can you please mention your email ID?

Comment: If you include the javascript you have tried so far in your question I may be able to help. It is expected that all questions contain a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0):

```
// left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40,
// spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36
var keys = [37, 38, 39, 40];

function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
      e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;  
}

function keydown(e) {
    for (var i = keys.length; i--;) {
        if (e.keyCode === keys[i]) {
            preventDefault(e);
            return;
        }
    }
}

function wheel(e) {
  preventDefault(e);
}

function disable_scroll() {
  if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
  }
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
  document.onkeydown = keydown;
}

function enable_scroll() {
    if (window.removeEventListener) {
        window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
    }
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = document.onkeydown = null;  
}


you can check the demo also

http://jsbin.com/disable-scrolling/1
```